# Combining text in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My JS looks like this:

```
preLoadImages("/media/img/elements/frontpage/1.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/2.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/3.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/4.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/5.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/6.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/7.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/8.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/9.jpg","/media/img/elements/frontpage/10.jpg");
```

What would be a better way to do this?

```
var directory = "/media/img/elements/frontpage/"

preLoadImages(directory+"1.jpg",directory+"2.jpg",directory+"3.jpg",directory+"4.jpg",directory+"5.jpg",directory+"6.jpg",directory+"7.jpg",directory+"8.jpg",directory+"9.jpg",directory+"10.jpg");
```

Doesn't seem much better. There must be a zip/map/join type thing I can use here?

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you can try apply(), then you can pass in the image paths as an array:

```
preLoadIamges.apply(this, absoluteFileNames)
```

then you can build you array in a the way you like, perhaps looking at [this unobtrusive implementation of Array.map](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm):

```
var directory = "/media/img/elements/frontpage/"
var fileNames = ["1.jpg","...","9.jpg"]; 
var absoluteFileNames = fileNames.map(function (value) { 
    return directory + value; 
});
```

Comment: Good answer, this is probably how I would approach it too.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are all named sequentially, doesn't using a simple loop make sense?

```
var directory = "/media/img/elements/frontpage/",
    images = [],
    i = 11;

while (--i) {
    images.push(directory + i + ".jpg");
}

preLoadImages(images);

// ...

function preLoadImages(images) {
    console.log("preloading: " + images);
    // TODO: preload stuff
}
```